# Debian package : where is the right place to put temporary installation files?

Tags: debian, package, dpkg, lintian

I am trying to build a binary package for Debian (with `dpkg-deb --build`) and I need to copy some files into the target machine to complete the installation with a `postinst` script (and remove them just after).

But I don't know where to put them.

I have tried `/tmp/mypkg`, `/bin/mypkgtmp/`, `/usr/share/mypkg/tmp`.
But Lintian has produced error/warning for all of them :

- [dir-or-file-in-tmp](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-tmp.html)
- [arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share.html)
- [subdir-in-usr-bin](http://lintian.debian.org/tags/subdir-in-usr-bin.html)

It's a directory with some binaries so the only place I can use seems to be `/usr/bin/mh`.

But `/usr/bin/mh` seems to be related to mail handling (not really clear).

**What's the right place to put my temporary files without producing a Lintian error or warning ?**

Here is my actual tree :

```
.tmp
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   └── postinst
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   ├── mypkg
    │   └── mh
    │       └── mypkgtmp
    │           ├── build
    │           │   └── lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    │           │       ├── myClib.cpython-34m.so
    │           │       └── mytools.py
    │           └── setupCython.py
    └── share
        └── doc
            └── mypkg
                ├── changelog.gz
                └── copyright
```

Thx.

Comment: Just to understand, You mean temporary file in binary packages, that should be deleted after installation, or temporary files to build a package?

Comment: And maybe could you explain what kind of temporary file. Often it could cause more problem (if the first case). Installation must be idempotent. With removal or upgrade of packages, the various pre/post-install/remove are called. Try to avoid having a temporary file: or do "calculation" it at building time, or install the support file.

Comment: What it is the exact lintian error? Having the root of package as `.tmp` is also non standard. You should use the package name `-` version. An hidden file as base is bad. (not sure all tools handle this well).

Comment: .tmp is just for building my package. Just after, I rename it with the good name.

Comment: My temp files are binary produced by cython (`myClib.cpython-34m.so`) and a pure python file (`mytools.py`) that I want to install with a `setup.py`. There should be no compilation. Just a copy, but managed by python. I think it is the good way.

Comment: yeah, but it is not a good name. Some tools copy the sources, lintian check also outside that dir. Really try from the beginning to use useful names.

Comment: Here is the errors I get : https://lintian.debian.org/tags/dir-or-file-in-tmp.html https://lintian.debian.org/tags/arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share.html https://lintian.debian.org/tags/subdir-in-usr-bin.html

Comment: Add such errors on the question. I still convinced that the error is from the `.tmp`

Comment: `mh` is a mail client. On systems where it is installed, you *certainly* cannot overwrite `/usr/bin/mh` with a temporary directory. (The reason there is a loophole there I guess is that multiple packages provide this file. I guess you could write to `/usr/bin/vi` as well for the saoe reason. I hope this will convince you to not do that.)

Comment: @tripleee : yes I am convinced (even if `/usr/bin/mh` is a [directory](http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/MAN/MAN1/0299____.HTM)), but I am searching for another way (simple) that I don't find.

Comment: @doom where did you end up putting your temp files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put files in `/usr/lib/mypkg/` and just leave them there even if they are not necessary or useful after `postinst`.

There is a (weak) hint that the packager may opt for convenience to use this for both architecture-independent and architecture-dependent files in [Policy section 9.1.1](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#file-system-structure) though of course your specific `postinst` scenario isn't covered there.

Comment: This produce the [Lintian arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share error](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/arch-dependent-file-in-usr-share.html)

Comment: Updated with the correct location and a policy link

Answer (score 0):

Keep them inside the source directory. Maybe there you create there a `tmp`. Object file (`.o`) and other intermediate file are generated and keep there. Just do no put them in the output directory `$(DESTDIR)`, so they will not be included in the package. And do no put outside building directory, so that building tools have no problems insulating your package from the rest of build system).

Comment: Your answer is for a src or bin package ? I have added the tree of my package. Where should I put the tmp folder ?

Comment: source package is done by sources, possibly unmodified. So you should have no temporary files or other files. If you tamper the sources, it is no more a source package. Now in your question, you are displaying the DESTDIR (so the output).

Comment: The tree I exposed here is not the output, but really the input of the `dpkg-deb --build .tmp` command

Answer (score 0):

If the files are only useful to the `postinst` script, perhaps you could simply embed them into it? A here document is a convenient way to keep a set of data chunks inside your script (maybe base64-encoded or similar if they are not plain text).

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
t=$(mktemp -t -d mypostinst.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -rf "$t"' EXIT ERROR INT HUP TERM
cat <<\: >"$t"/somedata.txt
some
verbatim
text
:
base64 <<\: >"$t"/somebinary.dat
deadbeefc0ffeeman===
:
```

If your needs are slightly more complex, maybe also look into `shar`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but prefer not going into this kind of complex solution. Seems to work with `mh` but don't think it was the right place.

Comment: Polluting the `mh` namespace with unrelated files certainly *ought to* produce a warning.

Comment: I'm saying it *should,* not that it *does.*